# How can I make a drop-down in MVC populated by distinct values in a database that will display all rows that contain the value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a table set up like so:

*AuditInfo*

```
ID (PK,int)
AuditWeek
LogType(nvarchar(50))
DateUploaded(nvarchar(50))
UploadedBy(nvarchar(50))
```

Here is some sample data associated with this table:

```
ID     AuditWeek   LogType   DateUploaded   UploadedBy
1 --- 19 May 2019 --- OS --- 23 May 2019 --- john.doe
2 --- 19 May 2019 --- DB --- 24 May 2019 --- john.doe
3 --- 26 May 2019 --- DB --- 25 May 2019 --- bill.doe
4 --- 26 May 2019 --- OS --- 27 May 2019 --- john.doe
5 --- 26 May 2019 --- AP --- 27 May 2019 --- jake.thorn
6 --- 26 May 2019 --- AP --- 28 May 2019 --- sall.nye
7 --- 02 Jun 2019 --- OS --- 03 Jun 2019 --- jaye.blake
```

I'm trying to get a dropdown that is populated based on the distinct Audit Week, that will display all the data for that week associated with the selection. So, for this given data, the drop down menu might be like this:

```
--Select Date--
02 Jun 2019
26 May 2019
19 May 2019
```

If the user were to select 26 May 2019, the following result were appear within a page:

```
ID     AuditWeek   LogType   DateUploaded   UploadedBy
3 --- 26 May 2019 --- DB --- 25 May 2019 --- bill.doe
4 --- 26 May 2019 --- OS --- 27 May 2019 --- john.doe
5 --- 26 May 2019 --- AP --- 27 May 2019 --- jake.thorn
6 --- 26 May 2019 --- AP --- 28 May 2019 --- sall.nye
```

With this information, how could I accomplish what I need to do in ASP.NET MVC?

My current idea is to have a Partial View that I load within my page. I could then have an AJAX call update this partial view based on the selection that was made. With this idea, I did some research and found a tutorial doing something similar to what I want: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/partial-view-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

I am following this at the "Rendering a Partial View using Ajax" section. That said, I am just lost in the sauce here on what I need to do make this work. Currently, I have the following:

**Model**

*AuditDataModel.edmx*

```
namespace AuditLogReview.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AuditData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AuditWeek { get; set; }
        public string LogType { get; set; }
        public string DateUploaded { get; set; }
        public string UploadedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View Model**

*AuditDataWeekVM.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AuditLogReview.Models;

namespace AuditLogReview.ViewModels
{
    public class AuditDataWeekVM
    {
        public AuditDataWeekVM()
        {
           AuditWeek  = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        public List <SelectListItem> AuditWeek
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

*Index.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<AuditLogReview.Models.AuditData>

<h2>Audit Data For This Week</h2>
Need a different week? @Html.DropDownList("AuditWeek", new SelectList(ViewBag.Dates, "AuditWeekDate"))
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AuditWeek)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LogType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateUploaded)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UploadedBy)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.AuditWeek
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateUploaded)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadedBy)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**Controller**

*HomeController.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AuditLogReview.Models;
using AuditLogReview.ViewModels;

namespace AuditLogReview.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private Entities db = new Entities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
            int diff = ((7 + (today - DayOfWeek.Sunday)) % 7)+1;
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(diff*-1);
            ViewBag.Dates = db.AuditData.OrderBy(m => m.ID).Select(m => m.AuditWeek).Distinct().ToList();
            return View(db.AuditData.ToList().Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.AuditWeek) >= date));
        }
    }
}
```

From the code, I have the drop-down at least populating with distinct dates. But I don't think this is how the tutorial I found is doing it - in fact, I think I'm supposed to use a View Model for this.

I am also completely lost on how exactly I am supposed to create the partial view... I think the idea is to use the View I have already posted above to be used instead as a partial view and feed it my ViewModel. I think I could keep the page, and the cut and paste the stuff for the AuditWeek into that partial view, and then put a @Html.Partial or something on the original page that references the partial view.

But how exactly can I handle this in the controller? Am I using two controllers here, or doing everything in just one? Again, the website https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/partial-view-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ seems to have something along the lines of what I need, I'm just having trouble implementing this. Also, am I doing my View Model correctly?

Would really appreciate any help on this matter!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully solve it without using any AJAX. Here is what I did to resolve my issue:

**Model**

*Same code as before.*

**View Model**

*Same code as before.*

**View**

*Table moved to partial view*

```
<h2>Audit Data For This Week</h2>
Need a different week? @Html.DropDownList("AuditWeek", new SelectList(ViewBag.Dates, "AuditWeekDate"), "--Select--")
<div id="AuditWeekPartial">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_AuditWeekInfo", Model);}
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#AuditWeek').change(function () {
            var selectedcolor = $('#AuditWeek').val();
            var link = '@Url.Action("GetAuditWeek","Home", new { dropDownChoice = "replace" })';
            link = link.replace("replace", selectedcolor)
            $('#AuditWeekPartial').load(link);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model AuditLogReview.ViewModels.AuditDataWeekVM
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            AuditWeek
        </th>
        <th>
            LogType
        </th>
        <th>
            DateUploaded
        </th>
        <th>
            UploadedBy
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.AuditWeek)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.AuditWeek
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateUploaded)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadedBy)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
        int diff = ((7 + (today - DayOfWeek.Sunday)) % 7)+1+7;
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(diff*-1);             

        ViewBag.Dates = db.AuditData.OrderBy(m => m.ID).Select(m => m.AuditWeek).Distinct().ToList();
        AuditDataWeekVM adwvm = new AuditDataWeekVM();
        adwvm.AuditWeek = db.AuditData.ToList().Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.AuditWeek) >= date);
        return View(adwvm);
    }

    public ActionResult GetAuditWeek(string dropDownChoice)
    {
        AuditDataWeekVM adwvm = new AuditDataWeekVM();
        adwvm.AuditWeek = db.AuditData.Where(x => x.AuditWeek == dropDownChoice).ToList();
        return View("~/Views/Home/_AuditWeekInfo.cshtml",adwvm);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a partial view in the shared folder of the project under Views, set the model binding to the model type which you will pass to the partial view, use ajax to pass the value of the drop down to the controller, return a partial view passing in the appropriate model, on success of ajax, populate the container

Partial View:

```
//Bind Model Type to Partial View
@model YourModel
```

Controller Action:

```
        //This can be just public IActionResult if you are not planning on 
        //using async methods inside of the controller action
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> YourGetMethod(string dropDownChoice) 
        {
            //Handle logic of drop down choice and populate the model accordingly
            return PartialView(partialViewName, YourModel);
        }
```

Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/YourController/YourGetMethod,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {dropDownChoice: yourDropDownChoice },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            //Clear your container
            //Append the data (partial view) to your container (div, etc.)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception){

        }
    });
```

Add `onChange` event callback to your drop down once DOM has loaded:

```
     document.getElementById('yourDropDown').addEventListener("change", function() 
     { //Call your ajax
     });

     //JQuery
     $('#yourDropDown').on('change', function() { //Call your ajax}
     );
```

)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I ended up finding a different way, but I appreciate you taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @nightmare637 You're welcome. I hope it helped in some way.